# MYSQL INNODB FULLTEXT INDEX

Tags: mysql, full-text-search, innodb, full-text-indexing

I am dealing with FULLTEXT Indexes in a big database ( with lot of update and insert every day)
So MYSQL est taking high CPU USAGE!

I have a question : Is there a way to rebuild indexes only one time per day? not every update/insert

Thank you

Comment: Did you do any research before asking? see [1](https://serverfault.com/questions/166398/when-do-i-reindex-my-mysql-database), [2](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/rebuilding-tables.html)

Comment: Of course I did but I did not find any information about my question!

Comment: Additional information request. 
RAM size, # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
F) complete MySQLTuner report 
AND Optional helpful information, if available includes -
htop OR top  for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a Linux/Unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I found my High CPU usage problem issue : In my database I have a function called by a query but never return result so process still in list ( never end)

So if you have a CPU Usage problem with Mysql: do not hesitate to inspect that using:

```
SHOW PROCESSLIST;
```

Comment: SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; has additional useful information.  i.e. more of query content.